# How to filter Prestashop product listing before it appears

Tags: filter, module, prestashop

I'm using Prestashop 1.8 for a Marketplace. Suppliers in my Prestashop can log in and manage their products.

I created a module, I have a custom table with id_employee <> id_supplier.

The Admin looks great for suppliers, and I can detect id_employee and get id_supplier.
All good.

The problem, is that they see ALL products. How can I filter the results shown in products in backoffice? I want to show all products that matches id_supplier.

I've tried overriding AdminController, from my Module using hooks like actionAdminProductsListingResultsModifier, displayAdminProductsListing

But nothing seems to affect the results shown... Any idea on how to filter the products?

Overriding AdminController seems to have no effect in Prestashop 1.8

Action hooks for filter results are triggering or don't know.

Comment: If you are using Prestashop 1.8 Disable the experimental feature new product page.
Then Hooks are working.
 
1- $this->registerHook('actionAdminProductsListingFieldsModifier')
2- public function hookActionAdminProductsListingFieldsModifier($params)

Answer (score 0):

Working.

1- Disable the experimental feature new product page. Then Hooks are working. 2- $this->registerHook('actionAdminProductsListingFieldsModifier')
3- public function hookActionAdminProductsListingFieldsModifier($params)

ActionAdminProductsListingFieldsModifier is the hook you are looking for, then you have access to  $params['sql_where'][]